# ¿Cómo hacer un nuevo arreglo atreves de laravel Controller?

Tags: laravel, array, arraylist

quería saber si laravel ofrece un método para hacer arreglos de este tipo, ya que desconosco si tiene un nombre en especifico para investigar.

Colección de la consulta original

```
[{"id":119,"color":"#1564C2"},
{"id":120,"color":"#FF2E31"},
{"id":121,"color":"#03AEEA"},
{"id":118,"color":"#FFCE2E"}]
```

Nuevo array

```
  id: ["119, "120", "121", "118]
  color:["#1564C2","#FF2E31", "#03AEEA", "#FFCE2E"]
```

La idea es que desdés ajax traer el atributo id o color de la consulta y me arroje esos datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener algo muy parecido (probablemente te sirva) con el método *pluck*

```
$arr_valores = Modelo::where(...)->...->pluck('color','id');
```

Esto te devolverá un array de la forma "id => color":

```
$arr_valores = array(
  '119' => '#1564C2',
  '120' => '#FF2E31',
  '121' => '#03AEEA',
  '122' => '#FFCE2E',

);
```

Échale un vistazo a la [documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck). Nunca viene mal.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el colleccion de laravel para crear la colección de arreglos.

```
$coleccion = collection(
   [id=119, color:'#1564C2'], 
   [id=120, color:'#03AEEA'],
   [id=121, color:'#FFCE2E']
);
```

Después lo puedes llamar usando el atributo `toJson()`.

```
$coleccion->toJson();
```

Este es la pagina de la documentación de [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-tojson).